# Apache port 8080 not listening - Possible firewall issues

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running an EC2 server with Ubuntu 14.04 & apache, and I have an app that uses the Ratchet websocket plugin for CakePHP. I have this working fine on localhost and I wanted to test the app on a server. When I SSH into my server and launch the shell script it runs fine. However, when I actually go to the page that uses the websocket connection, in the network tab on chrome it shows websocket(pending), and then it fails with the following error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://my.ip.address:8080/websocket' failed:
>   Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I used `telnet my.server.ip.address 80` and successfully connected. I was also able to connect to port 22, but promplty kicked off due to "protocol mismatch". I tried the same thing but on port 8080 and got a connection timeout.

**I was able to connect to port 8080 by ssh'ing into my server and using `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`**. I cannot do this from an outside computer, only from the local address from an SSH connection. I used `sudo tcpdump -i any port 8080` in a separte terminal that I was connected in via SSH, and the traffic of my telnet connection showed. So, I believe port 8080 is open and I can connect from the inside, but despite what UFW shows, all outside traffic to port 8080 appears to be blocked.

When developing on localhost, if I forget to enable the websocket server I get that same connection timeout error.

When I use `nmap -p 8080 my.server.ip.address` it shows the state as filtered. When I do the same for port 80 it shows state as open.

On my server I started the websocket and then In terminal I used `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` which indeed shows port 8080 is listening.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3532/php
```

When I stop the websocket and run the netstat command again, it goes away

On my local machine (which the websocket works on) I opened another terminal and used `sudo tcpdump -i any port 8080` to monitor the live traffic. I opened my web browser and sure enough, all of the traffic through the websocket was captured. I did the same exact thing on my server and there was no activity displayed.

After some searching I found someone [on the Ratchet Plugin github issue page](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet/issues/31) who seemed to have a similar problem. The plugin's creator responded `Hey, regarding your first comment is that if you pass it through a webserver you have to set it up to proxy the websocket connections to Ratchet.`, but I'm not quite sure what that means. Is that in reference to a port listening, or does it mean something else?

Here is my UFW status

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
2222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as your firewall?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not a server guru so that's a possibility. I'll update my response with what UFW shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following:

- [Amazon EC2 Security Groups for Linux Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)
- [Security Groups for Your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

Comment: It's not a VPC instance so I can't select a security group now. Do I need to relaunch the server?

Comment: each instance has it's own security group, you should tweak it according to your needs (first link explains how to do it on non-VPC instances, and second link is for VPC instance).

Comment: That was it! I accepted your answer because you provided the links and gave more detail on how to go about changing the groups. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your port isn't open in your EC2 security group. Check your ec2 console to open the port with the security group tied to the server.

Comment: It's not a VPC, it's a "regular" EC2 instance. I cannot assign a security group when I select the instance and click actions. It's not a selectable option. Is there another way to edit/apply security rules?

Comment: Ec2 classic uses security groups as well. You can select security groups from the left side on the ec2 control panel.